# password validation not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

i need to make an html page when you put a password to. whenever the user insert the correct password he will be sent out to a website. if the user won't insert the correct password he will get a an error.(i need to do it with only javaScript.no jquery and stuff like that) this is what i did -

```
<form>
```

Write the password here:

```
<input type="text" id="putPass" name="go2" /> <br />
<input type="button" value="click here" id="press" onclick="pass()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var password = ["1234","abcd","0000","1111","4321"]
function pass()

document.getElementById("putPass").value.    //it says it has a syntax error and i dont know why...


if (this == password[])
{
document.write("good job!");    
}
else
{
alert("try again!");
}

</script>
```

thank you.

Comment: I hope you are aware that this is 100% no secure protection at all?

Comment: i know, i just need it for a task nothing more.

Comment: The dot at the end of the line is causing the syntax error, and missing curly brace pair for the function.

Comment: removed it, still error...

Comment: @shayk You are also missing curly brackets around your pass function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do that using this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/VAK3N/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="putPass" name="go2" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="click here" id="press" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var password = ["1234", "abcd", "0000", "1111", "4321"];
    document.getElementById('press').onclick = function () {
        var p = document.getElementById("putPass").value;
        if (password.indexOf(p) > -1) {
            alert("good job!");
        } else {
            alert("try again!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var password = ["1234","abcd","0000","1111","4321"];

function pass(){

var userPass = document.getElementById("putPass").value;

if (in_array(userPass, password)){
  document.write("good job!");    
}
else {
 alert("try again!");
}


}

function in_array(needle, haystack){

for(var key in haystack)
{
    if(needle === haystack[key])
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pass = document.getElementById("putPass").value;
var correct = false;

for (var i=0;i<password[].length;i++){
    if (password[i] == pass){
        correct = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (correct){
    document.write("good job!");    
} else {
    alert("try again!");
}
```

Not sure if that exact code will work, but I think that you need to check each password individually in a for loop, you can't compare strings with entire arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see first that you dont want to use jQuery. So then here is the working code for you.

JS:

```
var password = ["1234","abcd","0000","1111","4321"]
function pass(){

    var input = document.getElementById('putPass').value;
    var accepted= false;
    for(var pass in password){
        if(password[pass] == input ){
            accepted= true;
        }
    }
    if(accepted){
        alert('good job!');
    }else{
        alert('try again!');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="putPass" name="go2" /> <br />
<input type="button" value="click here" onClick="pass();" id="passSender"/>
</form>
```

Comment: He doesn't want jQuery.